# What's the rule of thumb on database layout as regards who has ownership?

Tags: database, parse-platform

I have a database and there are users and there are medical ids. The question is do I assign the medical Id to the user or the user to the medical Id. Is there a best practice? Is it up to me? Thank you.

I have two objects:

- The user
- And the medicalObject

Each user has at least one medicalObject, maybe more.

What the the best practice for modeling the data who owns what in this scenario?

Comment: Its definitely down-votable is incomplete, and closable as unclear about what's being asked or opinion based.  Maybe fix by describing what medicalId is and how the code plans to use the relationship.  What are your thoughts about pro/con of making the pointer from User->MedicalId vs. the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Is the medical ID the same as ObjectID? If it is, you could try:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

Under the ParseObject you have created, try:

```
yourObjectHere.put("User", user);
```

Comment: Your question at the top is a good one.  What is medicalId?  Then, it looks like you're saying, "suppose its an object (misleadingly named), The OP should model the relationship with a pointer column on the medicalId object, pointing to User".  But you don't support this with "why", and the suggested column name is capitalized (unorthodox) and the code relies on the "put()" method on PFObject (nonexistent).  I think your original point about medical Id would have made a good comment to the OP.